# 2 Dimensional Arrays (Java) - Printing a Triangle with Alphabets in Cyclic order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The query was to write a Java method which prints the following triangle based on the input given (of the number of alphabets, on each side of the triangle).

```
public void triangle(int side);
```

Output expected:
triangle(3)

```
* * A * *
* F * B *
E * D * C
```

triangle(4)

```
* * * A * * *
* * I * B * *
* H * * * C *
G * F * E * D
```

I've come up with a method which does just that, but the code that I've written with my limited experience is with more number of for loops. Can any of you can review my code and come up with suggestions or optimized code for the same problem?

```
public void triangle(int input) {
        int x = input;
        int y = 2 * input - 1;
        int mid = y / 2;
        char character = 'A';

        String[][] partitionArray1 = new String[x][y];
            \\Following for loop will add letters on the side-1
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                if (i + mid == j) {
                    partitionArray1[i][j] = "" + character++;
                } else {
                    partitionArray1[i][j] = "*";
                }
            }
        }
            \\Following for loop will add letters on the side-2 (horizontal)    
        for (int j = y - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            j--;
            if (j >= 0) {
                partitionArray1[x - 1][j] = "" + character++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
            \\Following for loop will add letters on the side-3
        for (int i = x - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                if ((i == mid - j) && (j < mid)) {
                    partitionArray1[i][j] = "" + character++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                System.out.print(partitionArray1[i][j] + "");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Is there an algorithm available to answer such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public static void triangle(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i == n-1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2*n-1; ++j)
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.printf("%c ", 'A' + 2*n-2-j/2);
                else
                    System.out.printf("* ");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 2*n-1; ++j) {
            if (j == n-1+i)
                System.out.printf("%c ", 'A'+i);
            else if (j == n-1-i)
                System.out.printf("%c ", 'A'+3*n-i-3);
            else
                System.out.printf("* ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The idea is to print row #`n` separately from the other. The rest of the row have exactly two element(except the first one which is a degenerated case) symmetrical with respect the center.

```
triangle(9);
* * * * * * * * A * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * X * B * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * W * * * C * * * * * * 
* * * * * V * * * * * D * * * * * 
* * * * U * * * * * * * E * * * * 
* * * T * * * * * * * * * F * * * 
* * S * * * * * * * * * * * G * * 
* R * * * * * * * * * * * * * H * 
Q * P * O * N * M * L * K * J * I
```

Comment: Pretty similar to the solution above, but love the idea of code minimization!

Comment: His solution might be similar, it's something like 7 times faster

Answer (score 1):

I was bored so i did it with one array

```
public static void mimi(int size){
  int sizetab=size*size*2;
  char res[] = new char[sizetab];
  Arrays.fill(res,'*');


  int pos=size-1;
  int JumpGoRight=(2*size)+1;
  int JumpGoLeft=2;
  char letter='A';
  boolean changed = false;

  int nbLetters = size -1;
  for (int s=size;s>1;s--)
    nbLetters+=2;

  int i=0;
  while(i<(size-1)){
    res[pos]=letter++;
    pos+=JumpGoRight;
    i++;
  }

  int limit=(sizetab-(size*2))+1;
  while(i<nbLetters){
      res[pos]=letter++;
      pos-=JumpGoLeft;
      if( !changed && (pos<limit) ){
        JumpGoLeft=(size*2)-1 ;
          changed=true;
      }
      i++;
  }


  int index = 0;
  int doublesize=size*2;
  for(char c: res){
    if( ((++index)%doublesize)==0)
      System.out.print('\n');
    else
      System.out.print(c);
  }
}
```